# Conversion to Date is not working after deploying application on IIS (remote system)

Tags: jquery, vb.net, date, iis

I am calling a Web method  written VB.NET n from java script which works fine when working on Visual studio.

```
Public Shared Function MyServiceRequest(ByVal Type As String, ByVal StartDateTime As String, ByVal EndDateTime As String,
   ByVal Sites() As String, ByVal Areas() As String,
   ByVal Eqs As String, ByVal Units() As String, ByVal Plants As String,
   ByVal Conformance() As String) As Object
  Dim SQLCon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
  Dim SQLCmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
  Dim SQLReader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
  Dim SQLSPCall As String



  Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
  Dim JsonOut As String

  Dim StartTime As DateTime
  Dim EndTime As DateTime
  Dim SpResult As Integer
  Dim ReturnMessage As String = ""


  //Errors here
  StartTime = CType(StartDateTime, DateTime)
  EndTime = CType(EndDateTime, DateTime)


  --Other Code
End Function
```

Then I am getting the error:

> {"Message":"Conversion from string \"30/05/2018 03:22 PM\" to 
>   type \u0027Date\u0027 is not valid.","StackTrace":"
>    at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDate(String Value)\r\n   at
>    TestApp.CIP.MyServiceRequest(String Type, String StartDateTime, String EndDateTime, String[] Sites, String[] Areas, String[]Sets, String[]Circuits, String[]Wash, String[] Conformance) in C:\Data\Projects\TestApp\App.aspx.vb:line 109","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidCastException"}

Whats wrong? If the date string format is wrong , it should also error out on visual studio dev server !!

Comment: I would guess that this is a locale problem. In Australia, 30/5/2018 is clearly 30th May. However, if the other machine is expecting a US date format, it would be trying to convert it to the 5th of <some unknown month>. Not provided as a answer because I don't know how to explicitly fix it.

Comment: set <globalization culture="Your culture"/> for example  <globalization culture="en-US"/>  in config file and try.

Comment: @Shree, Can you please answer with following snippet, <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-AU" />
  </system.web>, This will help others in future for sure. It just worked for me.

Comment: @Simsons ok and you got a solution. Happy for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion in comment 
adding this setting on config file solved the problem.

```
<system.web> 
 <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-AU" /> 
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim DateTimeFix As DateTime 'Fix time format (Example: 2010-12-31 14:60:60)
DateTime.TryParseExact(TimeToFix, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, DateTimeFix)
TimeToFix = DateTimeFix.ToString("HH:mm, dd MMM yyyy")' or whatever format you like
```